# VB.Net Office Spell Check issue

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a Network Deployed .Net 3.5 Windows Form VB.Net application that was referencing the Microsof Office 12.0 Library dll.

As of last week the following code was working, however, the operations team upgraded everyone's Office (not a major upgrade, just a minor upgrade).  Basically when the spell checker is running it is HIDDEN behind the VB.Net application and it appears that the application is now frozen.  When I look at the task manager I see the instance of Office running and when I set that program to the front (in the Task Manager) I see the Spell Check box and can continue through.  I'm not sure in my code what I'm missing to set the priority of the Spell Check box so that it is on top of the app.

As of today I used the 2.0.5 version of the 12.0 library but originally I was using 1.2.x of that dll.  However upgrading to the latest version did nothing.  I got the same results.

I should also note that I looked at a 3rd party Spell Checker (Component One) and that required customization in the dictionary.  So I'm hopeful that there is a way that I can use Office as it used to work just last week!

Any ideas or suggestions are welcomed:

```
'Check subject line
If Me.txtSubject.TextLength > 0 And Me.txtSubject.Enabled = True Then
    Dim objWA As New Word.Application

    'objWA.Visible = False
    Dim objWD As Word.Document = objWA.Documents.Add
    'objWA.WindowState = Word.WdWindowState.wdWindowStateNormal
    Try
        With objWD
            .Range.Text = Me.txtSubject.Text
            .Activate()
            .CheckSpelling()
            .Content.Copy()

            If Clipboard.GetDataObject.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text) Then
                Me.txtSubject.Text = CType(Clipboard.GetDataObject.GetData(DataFormats.Text), String)
            End If

            .Saved = True
            objWA.Visible = False
            .Close(Word.WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges)
        End With

        'Application.DoEvents()
        objWA.Quit()
        objWA.Visible = False   'need this to get around the save prompt pop up

    Catch compEx As COMException
        MessageBox.Show("Microsoft Word must be installed for Spell Check to run.", "CustomerServiceTool", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)

    Catch ex As Exception
        If Err.Number = 5 Then  'bypass Clipboard operation failed errors
            objWA.Visible = False
            objWA.Quit()
        Else
            MessageBox.Show(Err.Description, "CustomerServiceTool", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End If
    Finally
        objWD = Nothing
        objWA = Nothing
    End Try


End If

'Check Message body
If Me.txtResponse.Text.Length > 0 Then
    Dim objWA1 As New Word.Application
    ' Dim objWA1 As Word._Application
    ' objWA1 = New Word.Application

    objWA1.Visible = False
    Dim objWD1 As Word.Document = objWA1.Documents.Add

    Try
        objWD1.Activate()
        With objWD1
            .Range.Text = Me.txtResponse.Text

            .CheckSpelling()
            .Content.Copy()

            If Clipboard.GetDataObject.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text) Then
                Me.txtResponse.Text = CType(Clipboard.GetDataObject.GetData(DataFormats.Text), String)
            End If

            .Saved = True
            objWA1.Visible = False
            .Close(Word.WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges)
        End With


        'Application.DoEvents()
        objWA1.Quit()
        MessageBox.Show("The spelling check is complete.", "CustomerServiceTool", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)

    Catch compEx As COMException
        MessageBox.Show("Microsoft Word must be installed for Spell Check to run.", "CustomerServiceTool", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)

    Catch ex As Exception
        If Err.Number = 5 Then  'bypass Clipboard operation failed errors
            objWA1.Visible = False
            objWA1.Quit()
        Else
            MessageBox.Show(Err.Description, "ASHLinkCST", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End If
    Finally
        objWD1 = Nothing
        objWA1 = Nothing
    End Try

End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of those, Administrator versus developer mysteries...  The Admin of the network say they did nothing, and the developer says he hasn't changed the code in 3 years...

So...  What we did was wound up buying a 3rd party component that is office independent...  It seems to have fixed the issue.